# If $x_i\leq 2x_j$ for every $i<j$ then there exists $y_1\leq y_2\leq\dots\leq y_n$ such that $y_i/2\le x_i\le y_i$ for all $i$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be positive integers with $x_i\leq 2x_j$ for $i<j$. Prove that there exist positive integers $y_1\leq y_2\leq\dots\leq y_n$ such that $x_i\in [y_i/2,y_i]$ for all $i$.

I tried to use induction. The base case $n=1$ is easy: choose $y_i=x_i$. For any $n\geq 2$, we can assume that $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{n-1}$ exist with $x_i\in [y_i/2,y_i]$ for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$. We know from the hypothesis that $x_n\geq x_i/2$ for all $i<n$. So $y_{n-1}\leq 2x_{n-1}\leq 4x_n$. This doesn't give a good enough bound to choose $y_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take $y_1=2\left\lceil\frac{x_1}{2}\right\rceil$.

If $x_i\le x_{i+1}$, then we can take $y_{i+1}=2\left\lceil\frac{x_{i+1}}{2}\right\rceil$.

If $x_i\gt x_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha=i+1,i+2,\cdots, j$ with $x_{j+1}\ge x_i,x_i\ge x_{i-1}$ and $y_i=2\left\lceil\frac{x_{i}}{2}\right\rceil$, then
since we have
$$x_\alpha\lt x_i\le 2x_\alpha\implies \left\lceil\frac{x_{i}}{2}\right\rceil\le x_\alpha\le 2\left\lceil\frac{x_{i}}{2}\right\rceil$$
we can take
$$y_\alpha=2\left\lceil\frac{x_{i}}{2}\right\rceil$$

The claim follows from these.

Comment: In the $x_i>x_\alpha$ case, why can you assume that $y_i=2\lceil\frac{x_i}{2}\rceil$?

Comment: @pi66: Because of $x_i\ge x_{i-1}$. As I wrote, if $x_i\le x_{i+1}$, then we can take $y_{i+1}=2\left\lceil x_{i+1}/2\right\rceil$.